# React MUI customize the Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a requirement to customize the MUI Select component to match this design

[image]

So far I have achieved this

[image]

There are two problems I am facing here now.

1. Favorite filters text needs to be vertically aligned to the center.
2. Arrow icon needs to be changed with the color itself.

How do I achieve these two using React js and MUI?

This is my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-firefly-rnexpl)